# How to write vbscript that numbers distinct rows or strings in csv file?

Tags: csv, vbscript

I need to duplicate efforts done in Excel using vbscript but am having a hard time learning vbscript, PLEASE HELP. The vbscript needs to open and read data from a csv file, then read data in column1, number each distinct (unique) string to column2 and any repeated or duplicate strings should have the same number.
Example of what result should look like:

```
column1: A B C C D E B F E A G, column2:  1 2 3 3 4 5 2 6 5 1 7
```

Below is what I have so far...not very much logic for manipulation yet because it already has errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, strInput, objInput
Dim arrValues, strItem, strLine
Dim strOutput, objOutput

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

strInput = "sample.csv"
strOutput = "New"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Open the input file for read access
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile_(strInput, ForReading)

' Open the output file for writing.
Set objOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutput, ForWriting)

' Read the file.
Do Until objInput.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objInput.ReadLine
' Skip blank lines.
If (Trim(strLine) <> "") Then
' Parse the fields in the file.
arrValues = CSVParse(strLine)
' Write the value in the first field to the output file.
objOutput.WriteLine arrValues(0)
End If
Loop

' Clean up.
objInput.Close
objOutput.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

The right tool for classification tasks in VBScript is the Dictionary. Demo:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> aC1 = Split("A B C C D E B F E A G")
>> For Each c In aC1
>>     If Not d.Exists(c) Then
>>        d(c) = 1 + d.Count
>>     End If
>>     WScript.Echo c, d(c)
>> Next
>>
A 1
B 2
C 3
C 3
D 4
E 5
B 2
F 6
E 5
A 1
G 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Can you explain more on how to use your suggestion into the script I have? I tried to use this and still got errors. Feel free to be extremely elementary in your explanation because I'm learning the very basics still.

Answer (score 0):

Record the steps in excel macro recorder. You have to rewrite it a bit because it uses a type of syntax that vbs doesn't.

This applies (I don't have a medium9) `xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4` in vba.

```
Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4, Number:=True, _
    Font:=True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

So first look up constants in vba's object browser. `xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 = 17`

Then look the function up in object browser and look at the bottom for the function definition,.

```
Function AutoFormat([Format As XlRangeAutoFormat = xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1], [Number], [Font], [Alignment], [Border], [Pattern], [Width])
```

So the vba becomes in vbs (and vbs works in vba) (and as you can see you can work out the correct way without needing to look the function up usually)

```
Selection.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

So your code becomes

```
objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

You are using Excel and you can record it in Excel and have Excel write your code.

Alt + T, M, R

then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.

Gee look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

Range("A1").Select